# How can I add enum menu to gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum InteractableMode // your custom enumeration
    {
        Item1,
        Item2,
        Item3
    };

    InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Item1;

    public float distance = 10f;

    [TextArea(1,10)]
    public string description = "";
}
```

I can see in the inspector the distance and the description fields but I don't see the enum menu when I attach the script to a gameobject.

I want to see the enum menu and to be able to select and change modes in the menu before running the game. The idea is to be able to decide one of two options if the gameobject is Interactable as Info item or also as Pickup.

If it's Info mode selected use it like now but if Pickup selected use as it now and also add/use an action method for pickup.

Comment: Have you tried making it `public` or does C# not accept that on an enum type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make enum public and field public or [SerializedField] private:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode // your custom enumeration
    {
        Item1,
        Item2,
        Item3
    };

    [SerializeField]
    private InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Item1;

    public float distance = 10f;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";
}
```

[image: Inspector]

Comment: So what the [SerializeField] attribute does after all ? I mean what was happens if I will set the variable to public too instead private and [SerializeField] ?

Comment: It simply lets you see and change this field in Unity Inspector, while it's still private for OOP purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to show up in the editor, Unity must be able to serialize `interactableMode`. To do this you can make it public (and then you would also have to make the `InteractableMode` enum public), or you can force Unity to serialize it by doing:

```
[SerializeField]
InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Item1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, i. e. making it `public` and instanciating it:

```
public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Item1;

    public enum InteractableMode // your custom enumeration
    {
        Item1,
        Item2,
        Item3
    };

    public float distance = 10f;

    [TextArea(1,10)]
    public string description = "";
}
```